# Div/Box Shadow Not Shows Everywhere EXCEPT IE10

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell why the following HTML and CSS shows the Box Shadow on every browser except IE10?  Did I miss something in Webkit?  Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="Testimonials">
<ul class="ca-menu">
<li>
<a href="testimonials.html">
<div class="ca-icon"><img src="_images/Testimonials.jpg" width="92%"></div>
<div class="ca-content">Testimonials</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Testimonials {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3%;
    width: 13%;
    display: block;
    border: thin;
    border-radius: 15.0%;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
    0 8px 0 #bfbfc2,
    0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,.35,.35);
    -moz-box-shadow:
    0 8px 0  #bfbfc2,
    0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,.35,.35);
    box-shadow:
    0 8px 0 #bfbfc2,
    0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,.35,.35);
    background-image: url(../_images/menu-bg%202.jpg);
   }
```

Comment: does it render correctly in IE9 ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and was kindly presented with the solution here: [box shadows not working in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565127/box-shadows-not-working-in-ie10)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

For some reason, it seems to help IE to render box-shadows.

Comment: I tried using border-collapse and it didn't have any effect.  Thanks though!