# box shadows not working in IE10

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a shadow to an element (right & left only).
It works in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari but not in IE10.
I'm kinda new to this so I'm thinking I must have make a mistake.
The link to the page: http://www.sytemaker.com/other-sites/ets
The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
width:300px;
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
box-shadow: 6px 0 4px  -4px #222, -6px 0 4px  -4px #222;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me, use `X-UA-Compatible` meta, seems like you are using old rendering engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE is probably not using IE10 mode, you can check with Developer Tools (press F12).

If not, the easiest fix is to add this inside head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! F12 did the trick. (Cursing the compatibility mode button ...) Would this meta code solve this issue for everybody else using compatibility mode, i.e. should I add it anyway?

Comment: Glad to help you, remind to accept the answer to help other guys with your same problem @Rolf

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target IE8 and earlier you can also use CSS property `-ms-filter`, but be aware that it is deprecated in IE9+. Details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For example:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=135, Color='#333333')";
```